# How to push project to ssh bitbucket repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

My goal is to push my project into empty ssh bitbucker repository. I have a rsa and rsa pub keys as a files. How can I reach my goal? Thank you.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Prerequisites: working installation of git on your computer, existing empty repository on Bitbucket server.

1) Set up a ssh connection from your computer to the Bitbucket server as explained here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

2) Attach your git repository to your remote using 'git init', then 'git remote add origin [url]' where [url] is the URL of your remote git repository. This is done from cli with the prompt pointing to your local repo's root (cd in there first of necessary)

3) Fetch, commit and push as usual on git. See git docu here (also explaining more on 2): https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Without further information on your OS this is not getting more precise, but the docu should get you going.